# Alamofire, Extra argument 'method' in call

Tags: alamofire, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I have google some answers with no luck, I got this error "Extra argument 'method' in call" and is pointing at the ".get", but if i remove the "headers : headers as? [String: Any]" it works. Please help

```
let urlParams:[String : Any] = [
        "target": target,
        "q": textToTranslate,
        "key": GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY,
        "source": source]

    let headers:[String : Any] = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                                  "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier": Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier as Any]

    // Fetch Request
    let urlString = TRANSLATE_API

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method : .get, parameters : urlParams as? [String: Any], encoding : JSONEncoding.default , headers : headers as? [String: Any]).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed header:[String : Any] to header:[String : String]

```
let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    let headers:[String : String] = ["Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier": bundleIdentifier]
```