# Extra argument in call Alamofire Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I've been trying to resolve this error when I call Alamofire by fixing parameter types, changing the response-type from `responseString` to `responseJSON` and force-unwrapping variables. I've checked out the following answers and haven't had any luck:

[Alamofire, Extra argument 'method' in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917624/alamofire-extra-argument-method-in-call)

[Extra argument 'method' in call of Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524950/extra-argument-method-in-call-of-alamofire)

[Swift - Extra Argument in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795035/swift-extra-argument-in-call)

[Swift 3.0, Alamofire 4.0 Extra argument 'method' in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113651/swift-3-0-alamofire-4-0-extra-argument-method-in-call)

Here's my code:

```
 func checkServerForLogin(email: String, password: String) {

    let parameters = [
        "email": email,
        "password": password
        ] as [String : Any]

    Alamofire.request(URL_CHECK_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {

            guard let data = response.data else {
                return
            }
            do {
                print("LOGIN_RESULT")
                print(response)

            } catch {
                print("ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call it...

```
AuthService.instance.checkServerForLogin(email: email_input, password: password_input) { response, error in

            if ((response) != nil){

            }
        }
```

I keep receiving `Extra argument 'password' in call`. Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `checkServerForLogin()` isn't a function in Alamofire, as far as I know.

Comment: Hey I made a singleton class, AuthService and then call the functions through there. Thanks though :)

Comment: Your method declaration `checkServerForLogin(email: String, password: String)` seems to have only two parameters whereas on function call, you are using three parameters i.e. `email`, `password` & an escaping closure paramter

Comment: Your function don't have the block parameter, thats why you have that error, It's not related to Alamofire, just your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have create simple method.you need to create completion block parameter

try this code

```
  class func checkServerForLogin(_ url:String,email: String, password: String,success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void) {

            let parameters = [
                "email": email,
                "password": password
                ] as [String : Any]

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { (response) in

                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    let resJson = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    success(resJson)
                }
                if response.result.isFailure {
                    let error : Error = response.result.error!
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
        }

AuthService.checkServerForLogin(URL_CHECK_LOGIN, email: email_input, password: password_input, success: { (responseObject) in
            print(responseObject)
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```